# How to get pthread object of boost::thread?

Tags: c++, boost, pthreads, boost-thread, thread-priority

I define boost thread using following syntax:

```
boost::thread *x=new boost::thread(function);
```

I need the **pthread_t** object of x.
after that i want to use prctl to set a name on that pthread_t object.
Is it possible?? 
If yes then how??